# AOSP Build TARGET_PRODUCT fails

Tags: arm, wolfram-mathematica, android-source, armv8

I'm trying to build an external tool with AOSP. My OS is Linux, Distribution ArchLinux (i3wm), but to compile AOSP I use Ubuntu in Docker (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/tools/docker)

**First step:**

```
# init repo
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-8.0.0_r36 --depth=1
repo sync
. build/envsetup.sh # set up environment
lunch aosp_arm-eng # select target to build
```

**Second step: select tool and build**

```
cd external/selinux
mma -j48
```

**Output:**

```
ninja: error: unknown target 'MODULES-IN-'
15:41:55 ninja failed with: exit status 1
make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/user/aosp'

#### make failed to build some targets (6 seconds) ###
```

**Another tool**

```
cd external/wpa_supplicant_8
mma -j48
```

**Output:**

```
ninja: error: unknown target 'MODULES-IN-external-wpa_supplicant_8'
15:41:55 ninja failed with: exit status 1
make: *** [run_soong_ui] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/user/aosp'

#### make failed to build some targets (2 seconds) ###
```

This happens with any aosp generic target:

```
Lunch menu... pick a combo:
     1. aosp_arm-eng                    # fails
     2. aosp_arm64-eng                  # fails
     3. aosp_mips-eng                   # fails
     4. aosp_mips64-eng                 # fails
     5. aosp_x86-eng                    # fails
     6. aosp_x86_64-eng                 # fails
     7. full_fugu-userdebug             # works
     8. aosp_fugu-userdebug             # works
     9. car_emu_arm64-userdebug         # fails
     10. car_emu_arm-userdebug          # fails
     11. car_emu_x86_64-userdebug       # fails
     12. car_emu_x86-userdebug          # fails
     13. mini_emulator_arm64-userdebug  # fails
     14. m_e_arm-userdebug              # fails
     15. m_e_mips64-eng                 # fails
     16. m_e_mips-userdebug             # fails
     17. mini_emulator_x86_64-userdebug # fails
     18. mini_emulator_x86-userdebug    # fails
     19. aosp_dragon-userdebug          # works
     20. aosp_dragon-eng                # works
     21. aosp_marlin-userdebug          # works
     22. aosp_marlin_svelte-userdebug   # works
     23. aosp_sailfish-userdebug        # works
     24. aosp_angler-userdebug          # works
     25. aosp_bullhead-userdebug        # works
     26. aosp_bullhead_svelte-userdebug # works
     27. hikey-userdebug                # works
```

I want to compile some binary tools in all arch: arm, arm64, x86 and x86_64.

Why aosp_arm-eng does not work? Or how can I change the CPU architecture from non generic aosp target?

Using `tapas` does not work.

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to make a full AOSP build before trying to use `mm...` shortcuts - looks like some build script files were not generated yet.

Answer (score 3):

clear all the binaries from /out dir with `make clean` command & then try to make a full build

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need to do a full build. Just open your Android.mk or Android.bp of the module you want to build, and look for variable MODULE_NAME.

Then from the root of the project make

```
mm $MODULE_NAME
```

It should build all the dependencies you need first.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that use the mmm command for building. Also make sure that the directory  you are pointing to contains a Android.bp or Android.mk

```
mmm /external/selinux
```

Also I suggest to clean the outputs by remove the out directory or simply run:

```
make clean
```

If still you have that problem, remove the --depth=1 argument on repo init and sync it again. that argument limits the commit fetching from remote branch.

Answer (score 0):

Use below commands to compile module from root dir

1. Goto root dir
2. make clean
3. source build/envsetup.sh
4. lunch "select option"
5. make "module name" -j8