# Is it possible to build AOSP inside a docker container with alpine flavour?

Tags: docker, github, dockerfile, devops, android-source

I'm very much new to AOSP and I'm trying setup the complete AOSP on the Docker to build a  Docker Image like Alpine or Ubuntu image, if it not possible please let me know the reasons why it is not possible to setup AOSP inside the docker image.

Or Do I need to write the Dockerfile to build the image?

Please help me if it possible with some good snippets.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: you can look into this https://github.com/sakebook/docker-android-alpine or https://github.com/Trumeet/AOSP-Build-Environment-Docker

Comment: Thank you for the quick responce @Adiii ...ill go through ...thanks once again :)

Answer (score 9):

Android team has provided a `Dockerfile`, `docker build` command to build the image, and `docker run` command to run a container : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/tools/docker

As mentioned there, you can mount your local AOSP source tree to the container using `-v` option in docker run command.

I have not tried to build AOSP in a Docker container. But in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57059394/2443657), @VasileM has mentioned that he uses the Android provided Docker instance to build AOSP.

Comment: Thank You for the response..really appreciated  @Lakindu , I'll check it

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out that there's a `Dockerfile` in AOSP `build` repo!

Comment: @Lakindu Can you please help me in same type of problem, please check the question once [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68363485/3946958)